# Why sometimes I need admin privileges to add the task using schtasks?

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

Why sometimes I need admin privileges to add the task using **schtasks**?
For example I can add following task without admin proivileges:

```
schtasks /Create /SC ONCE /TN testtask /ST 13:15 /F /TR "C:\\tmp\\scheduler\\test.cmd"
```

But I need admin privileges when I try to schedule a task which will be run by some event.
For example:

```
schtasks /Create /SC ONEVENT /MO "*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and EventID=4801]]" /EC Security /TN testtask /F /TR "C:\\tmp\\scheduler\\test.cmd"
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure in this case it's because you need admin access to read the Security event log, but that's mostly a guess. :)